# Target element by id somewhere within an element targeted by id

Tags: css

I'm trying to target an element by ID somewhere within an element which I have successfully targeted.

So this is the actual working CSS now:

```
#parentElement>div>div>div>#childElement {
  display: none;
}
```

I'm sure I must be having a bad day but what I really want to do, to make it a little more robust is just write CSS (not jQuery or JavaScript) to do the following:

for all `#childElement` within `#parentElement` apply `{ display: none; }`.

Is this a straightforward bit of CSS?

Comment: first you should not have multiple element with same id, and your solution would be #parentElement #childElement{display:none}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all #childElement within #parentElement apply { display: none; }
just write

```
#parentElement #childElement { display: none; }
```

It will be enough.

But you should knew, **id** recommended to bu unique, used only once per page. Use **class** instead for children.

Comment: Thanks.  What a wally! sorry I thought space was to make a list of items all work the same way.  I may follow your advice, but I'm using a modal control someone else wrote and am going for minimal change.  Although adding a couple of classes is pretty minimal...

Comment: List of items separates by comma ",")